# mod_rewrite issues: URL still showing the php variables in the url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have been working with mod_rewrite and cannot seem to get the URL to display nice, still showing the php variables in the url.

This is the current htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/display/([^/]+)$/([^/]+)\$ http://www.mydomain.tld/display.php?photo_id=$1&photo_size=$2 [NC]
```

Basically, I have tried everything to get a clean url like below to display:
http://www.mydomain.tld/display/3456/large

Answer (score 0):

Dont know, if thats really the problem, but it seems, there is a backslash and a dollar sign too much

```
^/display/([^/]+)$/([^/]+)\$
                 |        |

^/display/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
```

Comment: I tried that and same result, the page load now is a bit longer looking like it is attempting to rewrite .. any other suggestions?

Comment: still no luck:
RewriteRule ^display/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)$ http://www.domain.tld/display.php?photo_id=$1&photo_size=$2 [NC]

Answer (score 0):

well the rewrite works if you type in the URL into a browser .. so the mod_rewrite is doing it's job, but it's not re-writing the URL when accessed with the variables:

http://www.domain.tld/display.php?photo_id=2304&photo_size=Large (no rewrite)
http://www.domain.tld/display/2304/Large (works when typed)

Am I missing something somewhere?

Using the information from below, still not re-directing, not sure if I have the code placed wrong somewhere or if something with mod_rewrite is broken possibly inside apache.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule say you rewrite `http://www.domain.tld/display/2304/Large` to `http://www.domain.tld/display.php?photo_id=2304&photo_size=Large` (meaning the first is stored in the second place)

If you want the user that type `http://www.domain.tld/display.php?photo_id=2304&photo_size=Large` to be redirected to `http://www.domain.tld/display/2304/Large` you need :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^photo_id=([0-9]+)&photo_size=(.*)$
RewriteRule display.php /display/%1/%2 [R,L] #R to redirect, and then change the URL in the browser
```

and the you have to add something like

```
RewriteCond %{REDIRECT_URL} !^display.php$
RewriteRule ^/display/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ display.php?photo_id=$1&photo_size=$2
```

To avoid infinite loops.